# getting an error while using the library(tidyverse)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

getting the following error while trying to use `library(tidyverse)`

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘ggplot2’ 3.3.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.3.3 is required
```

I updated ggplot2 many times but still getting the error

Comment: Have you installed the tidyverse package? If not, in RStudio go to the Tools menu, then Install Packages, then search for tidyverse.

Comment: Do you have multiple library directories?  Check with `.libPaths()`.  According to the error, it's trying to load an old `ggplot2` version.  Possibly try *removing* `ggplot2`, then installing again:  `remove.packages("ggplot2")`, then `install.packages("ggplot2")`.  You can then check your package version to ensure it's `3.3.3` as required by the `tidyverse` package version you have installed.